# Github API Post Not Found 404

Tags: python, github, urllib2, github-api

For some reason, when I try to post githubs api to create a repository, I keep getting a 404 not found. Here's my code, has anyone else experienced this?

```
url = "https://api.github.com/users/repo"

headers = {
    "Content-type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "token %s" % self.config['token'],
}

request = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(data), headers)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    # print response
except Exception, e:    
    print e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the URL wrong; it's `https://api.github.com/user/repos` (`user` singular, `repos` plural), see  the [Repos create documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).

Comment: thanks ... stupid mistakes can really get ya sometimes. I also had improper admin rights on my token ...

Comment: The user resource on the URL is singular at this point. The docs now show `POST /user/repos` as the endpoint. It must have changed since this answer was created. For future reference for when people are reading this years down the road...this is v3 of the API.

Comment: @Matt: it may even have been a mistake on my part; corrected to reflect the current situation, in any case.